# Change of tenses

Tags: past-tense

What is the past progressive form of-
"I was ill"?
Can it be changed at all?
I think it cannot be changed but in a bit hesitation. Clarify the answer with reason.

Comment: I was being ill (regularly)? In practice probably 'I was falling ill regularly'.

Comment: You could also say "I was suffering from illness" maybe.

Comment: @WS2 Or *feeling ill*.

Comment: I always miss the obvious ones. Curse my large vocabulary!

Comment: Ill isn't a verb, so this is sort of a trick question. You might say "I was ailing" or "I ailed" if you were willing to resort to a slightly different word.

Comment: You can only make a past progressive from a present progressive.

Answer (score 1):

He was ill is not progressive, first of all.
To make it a progressive, one has to change it to:

to become ill or get ill

He is always becoming or getting or falling ill, present progressive

He was always becoming or getting or falling ill,past progressive

Answer (score 0):

***I was being ill***... although it's an unusual usage.  Perhaps because it can suggest a confusing sense of 'intent' that is not logical. 'Being ill' is not something you can control.  Diseases do not usually 'plan' to get you, nor do you, normally 'plan' to be ill.

I suppose someone looking back on unhappy school days might say  "I was being ill as often as I could so that I could stay home.  I would walk home through malarial swamps and the wards of sick children's hospitals as often as I could".